# how to add reason in discord.js ban and kick command with commando framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a `discord.js` bot with commando (which is the official framework/commands handler from the discord.js creator)
I have researched this subject on various websites and nothing seems to work with my commando framework.
This is the code

```js
const Commando = require("discord.js-commando");

module.exports = class banCommands extends (
  Commando.Command
) {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: "ban",
      aliases: ["bans"],
      group: "general",
      memberName: "ban",
      description: "Banned the mention member from the server",
    });
  }
  run(message) {
    const target = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (!target) {
      message.reply("you need to have at least one users mentioned");
      return;
    }
    const { guild } = message;
    const member = guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
    if (member.bannable) {
      guild.members.ban(member);
      message.reply("That user has been banned");
    } else {
      message.reply("You cannot ban that user.");
      console.log(target);
    }
  }
};
```

Any suggestion? or anything that have the same subject?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put it in the `options` argument (see the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=ban)). You should also probably use `member.ban` instead of `guild.members.ban(member)`, but anyways, here's an example:

```js
member.ban({
    reason: "Your reason here"
});
```

And the member will be banned, with the reasoning in audit logs showing up properly. You should add an `reason` argument to your command as well. Don't ask me how though, I haven't touched discord.js in a year and especially not commando. Check the guide for that. Make the mention the first argument and the reason the rest.