# Add a "reason" to a ban/kick in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to add a reason whenever someone ban a user, there is my code :

```js
bot.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ban")) {
        if (message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
            let ban_member = message.mentions.members.first();
            
            if (ban_member != undefined) {
               ban_member.ban();  
               message.channel.send(ban_member.displayName + " a bien été banni !");
            } else {
                message.reply("Cet utilisateur ne peut être banni!")
            } 
        }
    } 
});
```

I've searched everywhere but I could not find any one who can explain this
Thanks for future answer!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65161448/how-to-add-reason-in-discord-js-ban-and-kick-command-with-commando-framework/65161595#65161595) answer your question?

Comment: No, what you showed up is a predefined reason, what i want is a reason that the user specifies ! Like this : !ban @someone reason.

Comment: That is explained in the answer I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

```js
member.ban({reason: "your reason here"});
```

Comment: No, what you showed up is a predefined reason, what i want is a reason that the user specifies ! Like this : !ban @someone reason.

Comment: @XRHTech The most recent answer is right, but replace the reason definition with `args.slice(2).join(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide the reason of the ban through the command from Discord, you can get it from the message string and pass it to the `member.ban()` method.

If you split the message by spaces and remove the first two elements (`!ban` and `@username`), the rest of the message would be the reason. You can join the array by spaces again. Check this snippet below:

```js
const message = {
  content: '!ban @john_doe for being a real tool and telling lies!'
}

const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args[0];
const reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');

console.log({
  command,
  reason
})
```

You can update your code like this:

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    return;
  }
  const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args[0];

  // if the command is !ban but author can't ban, just exit
  if (command === '!ban' && !message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
    return;
  }

  const memberToBan = message.mentions.members.first();
  // remove the command and the mentioned user and join the words
  const reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');

  if (memberToBan) {
    // pass the reason
    memberToBan.ban({ reason });
    message.channel.send(`${memberToBan.displayName} a bien été banni!`);
  } else {
    message.reply('Cet utilisateur ne peut être banni!');
  }
});
```

Comment: This works like i said only if the reason is composed with 2 words, is there a method to take all the array after a interger, like take all values from an array after the args[2] for example ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. In my example if the message is `"!ban @john_doe for being a real tool and telling lies!"` the reason will be `"for being a real tool and telling lies!"`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: The problem is that the code only take the 2nd arguments (for in this case), not the whole sentence, that's why i asked

Comment: Can you tell me what the expected output would be for my example message? `"!ban @john_doe for being a real tool and telling lies!"`

Comment: The output will print : @john_doe has been banned for the reason : for

Comment: I'm pretty sure the above code doesn't only provide the first word as the `reason`. You can even click on the `Run code snippet` and check the result yourself. Have you copied my code correctly? Haven't you missed anything? It looks like you're using `args[2]` instead of `args.slice(2).join(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are not letting input a reason through the ban command.

*You need to define args in your command like this:*

```
let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
var reason = args[2];
```

**Implement**

```
ban_member.ban({reason: `${reason}`});
```

---

**Code:**

```
    bot.on("message", message => {
        if(message.author.bot) return;
        if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ban")) {
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    var reason = args[2];
            if (message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
                let ban_member = message.mentions.members.first();
                
                if (ban_member != undefined) {
                   ban_member.ban({reason: `${reason}`});  
                   message.channel.send(ban_member.displayName + " a bien été banni !");
                } else {
                    message.reply("Cet utilisateur ne peut être banni!")
                } 
            }
        } 
    });
```

*Hope it helps ;)*

Comment: _"All the answers are not letting input a reason through the ban command."_  Are you sure my answer from yesterday won't do that exactly? :)

Comment: I must be blind because I did not see that LOL

Comment: It's okay, but it was strange :D

Comment: It's working only if you have one arguments for the reason, it will only take the first word, so if i want to say : "test 1" for the reason, it will only returns "test" and not 1 (sorry for the delay french time ;) )